# How to save a page with html5 webstorage?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cookies

I have the following page, which works with MySQL, PHP and AJAX
if I click a NAME (id="orderN") it gives me back the result of the consult, which orders the names descending or ascending.
Is there any way that if you refresh(F5) the page, the result is saved as it was before closing, (ASC or DESC)?
I heard about cookies and HTML5 Storage, which is better than cookies.
if you can do it with either of them, let me know please

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><th><a href="#" id="orderN">Name</a></th></tr> 
    </table>
    <?
    $Conn = mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'root', '1234') or die('Error"');
    mysql_select_db('DATA');
    $consult = "SELECT NAME
            FROM STUDENTS";
    $query = mysql_query($consult);
    echo "<div id='DivConsult'><table>";
    while ($table = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $table['NAME'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>  ";}
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var contName = 0;
            $('#orderN').click(function() {
                contName++;
                if (contName % 2 !== 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "reOrder.php",
                        data: "tipOrder=ASC",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#DivConsult').html(data);
                        }});
                }
                if (contName % 2 == 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "reOrder.php",
                        data: "tipOrder=DESC",
                        success: function(data) {
                            //alert(data);
                            $('#DivConsult').html(data);
                        }});
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**AJAX:**

```
<?php
$Conn = mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'root', '1234') or die('Error"');
mysql_select_db('DATA');

$consult = "";

if (isset($_POST['tipOrder'])) {

 if ($_POST['tipOrder'] == 'ASC') {
    $consult = "SELECT NOMBRE
            FROM STUDENTS ORDER BY NAME ASC";
}
if ($_POST['tipOrder'] == 'DESC') {
    $consult = "SELECT NAME
            FROM STUDENTS ORDER BY NAME DESC";
}}`
  $query = mysql_query($consult);

echo "<table>";

while ($table = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $table['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>  ";}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but just saving a container (any div, span or even body) as

```
localStorage.variableName = document.getElementById("id");
```

And then you can access by using

```
if(Storage!=="undefined" && localStorage.variableName!=null)
```

now you can set value as

```
container.val = localStorage.variableName
```